# Show the location of the photograph that is displayed on ios lock screen

Tags: iphone, ios, photos.app

I have my lock screen configured to display `Natural` pictures, and change them hourly.  It would be nice to know where the photograph was taken (I have a lot of photographs, so I don't always recall the location).  Is there a way to do so?

I thought that long-pressing might open the photograph in `Photos`, but instead the action customizes the settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution.

- Long press the photo to get to the Customize screen
- Press the `Customize` button
- Touch the `Lock Screen` photo
- Press the ellipsis `(...)` button at the bottom-right corner
- Touch the `Show Photo in Library`
- Press the information `(i)` button

Comment: Consider marking your answer as accepted if it answers your problem as you said. It avoids it being bumped by Community bot as unsolved.